# error: request for member ‘stream’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a command stream to read, but I'm getting compiling problems or segmentation faults.  I want to access members in my struct command_stream, but I'll either get the "error: request for member 'stream'in something not a structure or union" or segmentation fault when I run it.  My code looks like this.

```
typedef struct command_stream *command_stream_t;

struct command_stream
{  
    int stream[100];
    int test;                                                                                                                                            
};

//get_next_byte is function that returns next byte in stream
//get_next_byte_argument is pointer to FILE

command_stream_t
make_command_stream (int (*get_next_byte) (void *),void *get_next_byte_argument)
{

  command_stream_t * ptr = checked_malloc(sizeof(struct command_stream));
  int c;
  int count = 0;
  while((c = get_next_byte(get_next_byte_argument)) != EOF )
  {

      //(*ptr)->stream[0] = 0;
      //(*ptr)->test = 0;                                                                                                                                
      //ptr->test = 0;
      //ptr->stream[count] = c;
      count++;
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

/////////////////////

checked_malloc is a function that is essentially malloc.
get_next_byte is essentially getc, and gets the next char in the file.
The problems are coming from ptr.  If I try ptr->test or ptr->stream[count], I get the error"request for member ‘stream’ in something not a structure or union".
If I try (*ptr)->stream[0] or (*ptr)->test, there's no compile error, but I get a segmentation fault.  What's wrong?

Comment: It either compiles or it doesn't - which is it? You said "but I'll either get the error ... or segmentation fault"

Answer (score 1):

Your type declarations are not consistent with your usage.  Because you have typedef that defines command_stream_t as pointer to struct, that means your variable ptr is actually a pointer to a pointer to a struct.  You either need to remove the * from your typedef or remove your * from the declaration of ptr.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` has the type `command_stream_t*`, which is the same as `struct command_stream **`. If you want your `ptr` to have the type `command_stream_t*` then you should change your typedef from `typedef struct command_stream* command_stream_t` to `typedef struct command_stream command_stream_t`. By doing this you use `ptr-><field>` like you wanted to.

That said, `(*ptr)-><field>` will not return a valid address. Hence the segfault.